# downloaded cataclysm, buying pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

OK so I have downloaded world of Warcraft cataclysm off the site, but I want pandaria now, my mom told be she would rather buy the disk then have me download it, if I were to buy the game from the store would I be able to play still even though the other versions are not store bought?

Comment: Note that you've already downloaded the game client, and so you don't need to install anything from the disc (and doing so could harm your installation). You only need to enter the code from inside the box into your Battle.net account.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you will be able to use a retail (box) version of MoP with your previously downloaded Cataclysm.

The important bit is the code that upgrades your account to have access to Mists, and you will get this in the box just as you would buying digitally.

Note that you may still have to patch the game after installing from the disk, which means you may still need to do some downloading of game content -- I'm not sure how much of the game content you will already have installed (via regular patches).